# Query with JOIN or WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) ...) >= 1?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database schema which contains about 20 tables. For the sake of my question, I simplify asking with only 3 tables :

```
* posts
    id
    title
    ...
* posts_users
    post_id
    user_id
    status (draft, published, etc)
    ...
* users
    id
    username
    ...
```

For reasons which are out of this topic, `Posts` and `Users` have a "many to many" relationship and the status field is part of `posts_users` (could have been in the `posts` table).

**I'd like to get published posts. I hesitate between 2 kinds of query:**

```
SELECT posts.*
FROM posts
INNER JOIN posts_users ON posts_users.post_id = posts.id
WHERE status = 'published'
```

**or**

```
SELECT posts.*
FROM posts
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM posts_users
    WHERE post_id = posts.id
        AND status = 'published'
) >= 1
```

(I have simplified my question, but in real, posts are linked to far more other data to filter)

My DB is SQLite. My questions are:

1. What is the difference?
2. Which way of querying is best in terms of performance?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about performance as much as readability. I would curse you every day for the rest of my life if I have to deal with your code that uses inner queries instead of a simple join. However, you could use `explain query plan` to find out: https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html

Comment: I don't like either query. See CL.'s answer on how to do this properly.

Answer (score 2):

These queries have different semantics: The first query returns multiple rows if more than one user has published a post (if that is even possible).

The SQLite query optimizer usually cannot rewrite very much, so what you write is likely to be how it is implemented. So your second query will count all `posts_users` entries, which is not necessary if you only want to find out if there is at least one. You should better use EXISTS for that.

An even simpler way to write the second query would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE id IN (SELECT post_id
             FROM posts_users
             WHERE status = 'published');
```

(This is one case where SQLite will rewrite it as a correlated subquery, if it estimates it to be more efficient.)

Ultimately, all these queries have to look up the same rows and will have similar performance; what matters most is that you have proper indexes. (But in this case, if most posts are published, an index on `status` would not help.)

Comment: Yes this is exactly how the query should be written. And your explanation is good, too.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you the perfomance of this query dependent of your row and column table.

At query 1 - Join is make

> Output.row = tableA.row * tableB.row
>
> Output.column = tableA.column * tableB.column

At query 2 - select count like that:

> Output.row = tableA.row + tableB.row
>
> Output.column = tableA.column + tableB.column

I recommend query 2 for more perfomance.